# x86 Assembly CALL Instruction Encoding

Tags: assembly, encoding, x86

How to encode the instruction near, absolute indirect call?

```
call r/m32
```

Its opcode is FF /2 and I know what does /2 mean but, How does it affect the encoding in binary form? Does it mean that we set the second bit to 1 in the ModR/M byte? Can anyone give me a complete example of how to encode a near indirect call, please?

Comment: The second bit of the reg field, yes. That is not the second bit of the modrm, rather, it is the 5th.

Comment: @Jester Hmm, ok. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/2 means that modR/m Byte uses only mod and r/m fields. The instruction has only one operand. It is a 32 bit displacement value. Therefore, mod = 00 and r/m = 101 (Displacement only mode)
and the reg field of the modR/m byte equals binary form of 2 in the notation /2 (reg = 010).

```
  ++++++++++++++++++++++++ 
  ||  Mod || Reg || R/M ||
  ++++++++++++++++++++++++
  ||  00  || 010 || 101 || = 15H
  ++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Answer (score 3):

`call [0x12345678]`

- opcode = 0xFF
- mod = 00b, reg = 010b, rm = 101b so modrm = 0x15
- disp32 = 0x12345678

Thus, `FF 15 78 56 34 12`